# SystemVerilog: copy a slice from a vector to another vector of different size

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog, hdl, asic

as per title, I want to copy a slice of fixed size from one vector to another, starting from a variable location.

Example:

```
logic[19:0]            in_vector;
logic[$clog2(20)-1:0]  in_vector_index;
logic[2:0]             in_vector_size;
logic[3:0]             out_vector;
logic[
...
always_comb begin
    out_vector = out_vector_r;
    // if the input is telling me that in_vector has something useful...
    if(in_vector_size > 0)begin

        // ...copy from in_vector at the specified position the max amount of data...
        // This may access the in_vector outside the range, copying X into out_vector, but I will clear them.
        out_vector = in_vector[in_vector_index +: 4];

        // ...maybe only a portion of data was valid and not all 4 bits.
        // So, "clear" to 0 out_vector from the specified position (decided by the size).
        // This may access the vector outside the range, but I don't care of what happens: I only care up to the max size of out_vector.
        if(in_vector_size[1:0] != 0)begin
            out_vector[in_vector_size[1:0] +: 4] = 0;
        end
     end
end
```

Now, this code works well in simulation. I wonder if there is a better way to code this, and if so which one. Also, do you see any criticality from the synthesis point of view?
I see I can access vectors outside of the range, but:

1. when I access the input vector outside of the range, I clear to 0 the possible X. I expect the same to happen after synthesis (??)
2. when I access the output vector outside of the range, I don't care what happens to the "extra" locations (that don't exist), I will not use them.

Thanks!

Comment: This code does not make sense as combinatorial logic. What's supposed to happen if `in_vector_size==0`?  Can you show example of what values you are expecting to see?

Comment: Hi @dave_59, sorry in the example I forgot to add the initialization. It is initialized from a register (which is not here in the example for brevity)

Comment: To expand, I want to copy only "in_vector_size" number of bits from in_vector into out_vector, starting from a specific position in in_vector.